# Maximum deflection of PSL + steel beam

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, deflection

I'm an amateur structural engineer, and I'm not understanding how to calculate multi-material beam deflection in my particular scenario.

I start with a simply supported PSL (wood) beam that is uniformly top loaded at 93 lbs/ft (including beam weight). It's 11.75" high by 3.5" wide. From consulting manufacturer websites, I use a Young's modulus of 2,000,000 psi, and a moment of inertia of 488 in^4. Over a span length of 34ft, I calculate that it will maximally deflect around 2.8". This approximately matches a real-world test.

I'm interested in theoretically calculating how much deflection there will be if I bolt A36 steel support plates on each side of this beam, assuming appropriate bolting pattern. If I assume these steel plates are 11" high and 1/2" thick, I think they have a MOI of around 55 in^4, each. I think A36 steel has a Young's modulus of 29,000,000 PSI. With this, I can calculate that if I *just* had these steel plates supporting the load (without any stiffness from the PSL) the deflection would be around 1.2".

How do I calculate deflection of the composite beam with the one PSL and two steel plates? I found some resources online about composite beams, but they all had the steel plates on the top and bottom, and that's not what I'm trying to consider, I want the plates to be on the side.

Comment: I suggest Google for the design of composite beams. What you need to learn is to transform one material to the other to form a beam with isotropic, homogeneous material.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the kind of technique I'd use? http://abe-research.illinois.edu/faculty/dickc/Engineering/compbeama.htm

Comment: Yes. Note this technique is valid for a fully composite build-up beam - no separation during deformation.